# Unable to make a simple calculation in django

Tags: django, django-views

i have a view and i am trying to perform a simple mathematical calculation and I am getting an error that is throwing me off.

So I have a method that will take in two variabes, a decimal value and a integer. I want to take the numbers and divide the decimal by the integer. I am getting the following error and I dont know why...

this is the method

```
def SplitEven(record, amount):
    record_count = record.count
    print(record_count)
    print(amount)
    split_amount = amount/record_count
    print(split_amount)
    rounded_amount = round(split_amount, 2)
    print (record_count)
    print (amount)
    print (split_amount)
    return rounded_amount
```

This is the error message:

```
unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'

C:\Users\OmarJandali\Desktop\opentab\opentab\tab\views.py in addTransaction
                                taxSplit = SplitEven(record, amount) 

C:\Users\OmarJandali\Desktop\opentab\opentab\tab\views.py in SplitEven
                split_amount = amount/record_count
```

Here is what comes up from the print statements:

```
[25/Jul/2017 16:14:10] "GET /static/css/blog.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1649
6
6
6.00
[25/Jul/2017 16:15:05] "POST /39/72/add_transaction/ HTTP/1.1" 500 83164
```

Comment: Try printing `type(record_count)` and `type(amount)`, and see what you get.

Comment: Yeah the amount is printing as a string....

Comment: So i had the input as a text and changed it to a number... but it is still showing up as a string....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from decimal import Decimal

def SplitEven(record, amount):
    record_count = Decimal(record.count)
    split_amount = Decimal(amount)/record_count
    rounded_amount = round(split_amount, 2)
    return rounded_amount
```

Comment: Do you know what the import statement is for Decimal

Comment: `from decimal import Decimal`